# Firestore instance creation getting crashed in direct boot mode in android

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, crash

While initializing the fire-store in direct boot mode in android, app getting crashed with below logs

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SharedPreferences in credential encrypted storage are not available until after user is unlocked
        at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences(ContextImpl.java:572)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences(ContextImpl.java:557)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:217)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzbi.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.0:6)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.0:12)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzv.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.0:1)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.zzs.create(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.0:3)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.lambda$discoverComponents$0(ComponentRuntime.java:132)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$$Lambda$1.get(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:53)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.auth.FirebaseAuthCredentialsProvider.lambda$new$1(FirebaseAuthCredentialsProvider.java:81)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.auth.FirebaseAuthCredentialsProvider$$Lambda$2.handle(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.firebase.components.OptionalProvider.whenAvailable(OptionalProvider.java:77)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.auth.FirebaseAuthCredentialsProvider.<init>(FirebaseAuthCredentialsProvider.java:78)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.newInstance(FirebaseFirestore.java:132)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirestoreMultiDbComponent.get(FirestoreMultiDbComponent.java:65)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(FirebaseFirestore.java:113)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(FirebaseFirestore.java:99)
```

However i have enabled the direct boot mode in application tag in manifest

```
android:directBootAware="true"
```

and followed : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#receive_fcm_messages_in_direct_boot_mode